Artifacts - Create and Upload Azure DevOps
I would like to create an artifact on a pipeline, and upload a file.
The following C# code create an artifact, but I don't see how to upload a file in this artifact :
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string collectionUri = "https://dev.azure.com/yourorganization"; // Update with your Azure DevOps Collection URI
            string project = "YourProjectName"; // Update with your Azure DevOps project name
            string buildId = "123"; // Update with your build ID
            string artifactName = "MyArtifact";

            // Create a VSS connection
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "PersonalAccessToken")); // Update with your personal access token

            // Create a Build client
            BuildHttpClient buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();

            // Local path of the file you want to publish
            string localPath = @"C:\path\to\your\file.txt"; // Update with the local path of your file

            // Create an ArtifactResource object
            ArtifactResource artifactResource = new ArtifactResource();
            artifactResource.Type = "FilePath";
            artifactResource.Data = localPath;

            // Create a BuildArtifact object
            BuildArtifact buildArtifact = new BuildArtifact();
            buildArtifact.Name = artifactName;
            buildArtifact.Resource = artifactResource;

            //----------------
            // What code I have to do to associate my file with the artifact and be uploaded ?
            //----------------

            // Publish the artifact
            await buildClient.CreateArtifactAsync(buildArtifact, project, int.Parse(buildId));

            Console.WriteLine("Artifact created successfully!");
        }
    }


I want to upload a file in my artifact on Azure DevOps. What code should I do ?

Hi Jean-Pierre, welcome to stackoverflow :-) Artifacts are files that are produced by a build. Why do you need to run this as a C# application, as opposed to simply running a pipeline that will generate the desired artifact?

My C# application runs in the pipeline and produce files to be published. It's should be easier for me to make all in C# instead of alternate executions of my C# application, and publishbuildartifacts task...

Uh I'm very very confused and still trying to understand why on earth do you need to do something like that. What is the purpose of the file you're trying to upload as an artifact? Will that file be generated by the console app?

Yes, it's a console app, and integrate a state machine. I have many steps to execute. Often after a steps I have to publish somes files. So currently I run some C# code, then I publish, then again C# code, then I publish... If I can have all my code in C#, it's should be easier, even for unit tests..


I want to upload a file in my artifact on Azure DevOps

It doesn't support. According to official doc BuildHttpClientBase.CreateArtifactAsync Method, this API is used to associate an artifact with a build. Which means that it needs an existed pipeline/build artifact instead of creating a new artifact for the build.
Artifact of the pipeline is based on azure storage, but this storage is invisible. For ArtifactResource Class, it has a property named Data, which needs a path of the artifact that already exists.
It's suggested that you use PublishPipelineArtifact@1 task and specify the path of your file from targetPath.

My C# application runs in the pipeline and produce files to be published.

In this case, consider using Azure Universal Artifacts: Publish and download universal packages in Azure Artifacts. You can authenticate with PAT through AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT variable: Sign in with a personal access token (PAT). Then use az artifacts universal publish and az artifacts universal download .

Cool stuff, didn't know about the universal packages. Thanks for sharing :-)

Ok, so now I have a (slightly) better understanding of your problem:

Yes, it's a console app, and integrate a state machine. I have many
steps to execute. Often after a steps I have to publish some files.
So currently I run some C# code, then I publish, then again C# code,
then I publish... If I can have all my code in C#, it's should be
easier, even for unit tests..

Even if it was possible, I honestly don't see how running everything inside the console app would make things easier.
My proposed solution is:

Console app: the only purpose should be to generate the files you need into an output folder. Not having any dependencies on any pipeline will make it easier to run the app in different contexts, such as your local machine, a pipeline etc
Pipeline: Runs the console app and publishes the generated files as artifacts

Something like:
variables:
  # Set folder where the generated files will be generated
  $ Use the artifacts folder or override a setting from appsettings.json
  outputFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

steps:
  # tasks to restore, build, test, and publish the console app

  # task to run the console app and generate files in $(outputFolder)

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(outputFolder)'
      artifactName: 'GeneratedFiles'

In your local machine you can test and debug your application in order to check if the files are generated correctly, and when you need to publish them just queue a new build of the pipeline that will run the console app.
